# How do I structure a join table with ObjectionJS?

Tags: javascript, relational-database, objection.js

I'm trying to create a datamodel that looks like this:

https://prnt.sc/mflh3t

Essentially, a user can belong to many projects, and a project can have many users. I figured I'd make a join table called `UserProjects`.

However, I'm not entirely sure what the structure looks like. My user model in Objection looks like this:

```
class User extends Model {
    static get tableName () {
      return 'user'
    }

    static get relationMappings () {
      return {
        timesheet: {
          relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
          modelClass: Timesheet,
          join: {
            from: 'user.id',
            to: 'timesheet.user_id'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Should I create two new schemas on `Project` and `User` along the lines of

```
 class Project extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
      return 'project'
    }
    static get relationMappings() {
      return {
        userprojects: {
          relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
          modelClass: UserProjects,
          join: {
            from: 'project.id',
            to: 'userprojects.project_id'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
class User extends Model {
    static get tableName () {
      return 'user'
    }

    static get relationMappings () {
      return {
        timesheet: {
          relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
          modelClass: Timesheet,
          join: {
            from: 'user.id',
            to: 'timesheet.user_id'
          }
        },
        userprojects: {
          relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
          modelClass: UserProjects,
          join: {
            from: 'user_id',
            to: 'userprojects.user_id'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In this scenario: how would I add users to a project? Through the `UserProjects` table?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method to add a project for the model User such as:

```
class User extends Model {
    static get tableName () {
      return 'user'
    }

    static get relationMappings () {
      return {
        timesheet: {
          relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
          modelClass: Timesheet,
          join: {
            from: 'user.id',
            to: 'timesheet.user_id'
          }
        },
        userprojects: {
          relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
          modelClass: UserProjects,
          join: {
            from: 'user.id',
            to: 'userprojects.user_id'
          }
        }
      }
    }

    static getModel(knex) {
        return User.bindKnex(knex)
    }

    static async getUser(knex, id) {
        return await User.getModel(knex).query().eager('[timesheet, userprojects]').where('id', id).first() 
    }

    async addProject(projectId){
        return await this.knex()
            .$relatedQuery('userprojects')
            .insert({project_id: projectId})
    }
}
```

Be advised, I didn't test anything, just wrote it here. But that's the way I would organize the code.